# Orthogonal polynomial and inner products problem

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials

$\{\phi_1, \phi_2,...\}$ are orthogonal polynomials with respect to some arbitrary real inner product but are normalised to be monic. The question doesnt say but I think $\phi_i$ is supposed to be of degree exactly $i$

If $p$ is any polynomial of degree $k$ show that $\|\phi_k\| \leq \|p\|$. (The norm induced from this inner product)

Edit: $p$ must be monic

Comment: I don't see how any of the numerical tags are relevant in here.

Comment: What's the linear space, what's the inner product, over what field...?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 It was in a num analysis sheet

Comment: @Joanpemo I've edited

Comment: @Arcane1729 When you say "normalized" then it is only about the monic thing, not that those vectors are orthonormal?

Comment: The statement as given couldn't possibly be true. Consider the sequence $p,p/10,p/100,p/1000\dots$. The statement asserts that each of these has norm exceeding that of $\phi_k$.

Comment: @Joanpemo yes only the monic thing

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe the question setter is hoping for me to assume the inner product is:  inner product of (f,g) is integral from a to b of w(x)*f(x)*g(x) where w is non-negative on (a,b).  We've been talking about that inner product a lot. It really is annoyingly ambiguous I'm sorry.

Comment: @Arcane1729 If you took this exercise from a sheet of paper without any more information then many things can be assumed but we can't be sure. Try to find out the exact meaning of the question.

Comment: @Joanpemo I'll edit again soon when I am sure

Comment: The exact nature of the inner product is irrelevant for my objection, Arcane. I've given you a sequence of polynomials with norm – *any* norm – going to zero, but the statement asserts they all have norm at least that of $\phi_k$. That can't happen.

Comment: I guess $p$ should be monic or normalized in some way?

Comment: @user251257 OHHHHHHHHH. I forgot that!

Comment: Notice that $p=\alpha \phi_k + q$ with $\deg q <k$. then use the orthogonality and the normalization.